# Netbeans indent guideline placement? variable-width fonts

Tags: java, netbeans, formatting, editor, indentation

I'm having a bit of trouble with the indent guideline placement in netbeans. I can't remember when the problem started, but it's extremely distracting. The guide lines just cut directly through lines of code instead of preceding the indented blocks of code.

[image: link]

*note - Auto format does not fix this (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Problem solved

The problem was the font. For some reason when I change the font from calibri to monospaced the indent lines are back to normal.  imgur [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NCDg.png) (font pictured is actually Inconsolota, no picture of calibri to monospaced)

I decided to do a little more digging and found out that mono-spaced actually varies depending on which OS is being used(courier in windows). Monospaced fonts keep all characters within the same proportions. So I'm guessing that calibri is a variable-width font(described in the wiki link). Netbeans must not adjust it's indent spacing to account for the changes in the font proportions. This causes the indent lines to look out of place, when actually the letter spacing is what throws the spacing out. I hope this information becomes useful to new users like myself. Unless you prefer the distracting lines and the squashed look, make sure the font in netbeans is a monospaced font. I recently started using Inconsolata in my editor and it's really grown on me. It looks better with Anti-A enabled in the editor so [here](https://g3n1k.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/enabling-anti-aliasing-netbeans-editor/) is how to enable the feature.

cheers
-shwig

Comment: I had the same issue with MS Reference Sans Serif